# Linking libraries in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I've been trying to compile this simple code for absolute ages but with no luck.

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
int main()
{    
   int cvNamedWindow(const char* name,int flags = CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   {
        cvNamedWindow("sample");
   }

   cvDestroyWindow("sample");    
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 platform. At first I was getting errors saying that

> highgui.h was not found.

I have now corrected that but now I am getting new ones. The compile instruction I am using is:

```
gcc -o window window.c -I/usr/include/opencv/
```

The new error is:

```
window.c:8:48: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token
window.c:10:6: error: too few arguments to function ‘cvNamedWindow’
```

Now I'm not even sure what the problem is anymore. There doesn't seem to be any clear explanation on  compilation in OpenCV. Please somebody help cos I really need to get a move on with this, can't be spending all day trying to just compile! Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the syntax?!

Comment: I'm not even sure anymore. Do u see anything wrong?

Comment: @user2035796... Do you know how to write C code? This is invalid C code.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling this:

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
int main() {    
   cvNamedWindow("sample");


   cvDestroyWindow("sample");
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It keeps saying "too few arguments in cvNamedWindow"

Comment: @user2035796... Thats because you are using `gcc` which can't compile the above mentioned C++ code. `cvNamedWindow` takes 2 arguments. In `C` there are no default arguments. You have to pass all the arguments to the function. Pass `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` as the second argument to `cvNamedWindow`.

Comment: use cvNamedWindow("sample", 0); where '0' means you can resize the window and '1' cannot resize.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no default arguments in C**.

You should call `cvNamedWindow()` as follows:

```
cvNamedWindow("sample", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

Full code:

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"

int main() {    
   cvNamedWindow("sample",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cvDestroyWindow("sample");
   return 0;
}
```